# Loops en RStudio

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio

Soy nuevo con R, estoy intentado realizar un loop o bucle. He probado esto con un sólo valor (120) y me funciona correctamente.

```
for (i in 1:10000){

  m1 <- ifelse(datos$AÑO1 < 120,'Falso','Verdadero')

  m2 <- ifelse(datos$AÑO2 < 120,'Falso','Verdadero')

  table <- ifelse((m1=='Verdadero')&(m2=='Verdadero'), 'VERDADERO', 'FALSO')

}

z <- data.frame(table)
```

Ahora quisiera hacer lo mismo pero para más valores, puesto que solo me estoy limitando en un valor que es el 120. En lugar de eso quisiera usar todos los valores comprendidos entre 0 y 300 e ir guardando todos los resultados en una matriz.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leyendo tú código, entiendo que en primer lugar estas buscando determinar si dos variables sean menores a 120. La primera observación es ¿para que un ciclo? R es un lenguaje que trabaja nativamente con vectores, lo que estás haciendo ahora es repetir 10000 veces exactamente lo mismo. Supongamos algo así:

```
datos <- data.frame(ANO1=sample(115:123, 100, replace = TRUE),
                    ANO2=sample(115:123, 100, replace = TRUE))
head(datos)

  ANO1 ANO2
1  120  121
2  119  118
3  119  117
4  117  123
5  118  120
6  118  120
```

La forma habitual de hacer esto, es agregar una nueva variable al `data.frame`:

```
datos$Menor120 <- ifelse(datos$ANO1 < 120 & datos$ANO2 < 120,'VERDADERO','FALSO')
head(datos)

 ANO1 ANO2  Menor120
1  120  121     FALSO
2  119  118 VERDADERO
3  119  117 VERDADERO
4  117  123     FALSO
5  118  120     FALSO
6  118  120     FALSO
```

`ifelse()` es una función vectorizada, la función de comparación `<` también, asi que podemos trabajar directamente con la columna completa, el resultado de `datos$ANO1 < 120 & datos$ANO2 < 120` es un vector de lógicos consistente con cada fila, el resultado final será otro vector con la cadena `VERDADERO` o `FALSO` también para cada fila.

¿Ahora quieres verificar otra condición? no hay más que repetir este proceso, si quieres verificar que las dos variables están dentro de un rango, puedes hacer:

```
datos$De0a300 <- ifelse(datos$ANO1 > 0 & datos$ANO1 < 300 &
                        datos$ANO2 > 0 & datos$ANO2 < 300,
                        'VERDADERO','FALSO')
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Gracias. Nada más como se debería realizar para todos los valores comprendidos entre  0 y 300?

Comment: @Santiago, no sé si entiendo muy bien lo que dices, ¿que es lo que buscas? ver si los dos valores son menores a 1, si son menores a 2 y así hasta 300?

Comment: Si, exactamente eso. Y guardar los resultados en una matriz

Comment: @Santiago,  Si no entendí mal tu último comentario, reformule tu pregunta en una nueva, revisala: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296735/como-construir-una-matriz-producto-de-una-comparaci%c3%b3n-con-un-rango-de-valores/296736#296736

Comment: Excelente. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No se si entiendo muy bien tu pregunta... Intenta especificar más. Por si acaso, lo que yo entiendo es que quieres establecer si ANO1 y ANO2 está entre 0 y 300. Simplemente es añadir una condición extra:

```
for (i in 1:10000){

  m1 <- ifelse(datos$ANO1 < 0 || datos$ANO1>300,'Falso','Verdadero')

  m2 <- ifelse(datos$ANO2 < 0 || datos$ANO2>300,'Falso','Verdadero')

  table <- ifelse((m1=='Verdadero')&(m2=='Verdadero'), 'VERDADERO', 'FALSO')

}

z <- data.frame(table)
```

Comment: Tú código tiene un problema, estás usando el `OR` no vectorizado, el doble pipe, esto solo verifica la condición del primer elemento del vector y no de todos, deberías reemplazarlo por el pipe simple `|` que sí es vectorizado.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Quiero comparar si AÑO1 y AÑO2 es menor para cada uno de los valores de (0, 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , ... , 300).

Comment: tienes razón @PatricioMoracho, la costumbre con otros lenguajes ;)