# ¿Cómo construir una matriz producto de una comparación con un rango de valores?

Tags: r

Vamos a suponer que tenemos un `data.frame` como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2019)
datos <- data.frame(ANO1=sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    ANO2=sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
datos

   ANO1 ANO2
1     8    8
2     8    7
3     4    3
4     7    2
5     1    7
6     1    7
7     9    1
8     1    8
9     2    4
10    7    5
```

Lo que busco, es crear una matriz con el valor lógico de comparar si las dos columnas son menores a un determinado conjunto de números, por ejemplo, digamos un rango de 1 a 10, tomando como referencia la primer fila, quisiera obtener algo como esto:

```
   ANO1 ANO2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   10
1     8    8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

En este caso los dos `8` son menores a `10` y `9` pero no menores al resto de los valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma que se me ocurre es crear una matriz de referencia para comparar, es decir vamos a crear una matriz con los 10 "comparables" y la cantidad de filas del `data.frame`, es decir:

```
nr <- nrow(datos)
mref <- matrix(rep(1:10, nr), nrow = nr , byrow = TRUE)
mref

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [9,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
[10,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Teniendo esto, y gracias a que las comparaciones en realidad son funciones es que podríamos comparar individualmente cada columna con su valor de referencia:

```
a <- `<`(datos$ANO1, mref)
b <- `<`(datos$ANO2, mref)
```

Nota: originalmente pensé que no iba funcionar, pero también es totalmente válido hacer:

```
a <- datos$ANO1 < mref
b <- datos$ANO2 < mref
```

Y ahora simplemente nos aseguramos que ambas columnas sean menores al valor de referencia con un `&` (`and` lógico matricial), la combinación de los resultados es solo a efectos de constatar el resultados:

```
cbind(datos, a & b)

   ANO1 ANO2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   10
1     8    8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
2     8    7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
3     4    3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
4     7    2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
5     1    7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
6     1    7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
7     9    1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
8     1    8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
9     2    4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
10    7    5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```